# How can I populate an array field without ref in MongoDB (mongoose)?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, populate

I have a Schema that contains an array field. In this array field I'll insert objects that contains the author's _id and an author's comment.
I want populate this field, but my Schema don't have ref.

that's my Schemas

```
const Book = new Schema({
    name: {
        type:String,
        required: true 
    }
    authors: [{
        type: Array
    }]
})

const Author = new Schema({
    name: {
        type:String,
        required: true 
    }
    (... author's data)
})
```

I will insert objects in authors field of Book collection:

```
insertAuthor = {
        _id:id,
        comment: 'comment'
    }
```

It's working fine, but I can't populate the authors field.

Can anybody help me with this?

Thank you!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can specify the `model` in the `populate` if the `ref` is not defined in the `Schema`. So from what I understand you need to query the `Book` by populating  `Author`.

```js
const books = await Book.find().populate({path: 'authors._id', model: 'Author'}).exec();
```

Also in your `Book` schema if you are inserting a JSON object as mentioned in your question then don't need to define `type: Array` inside the JSON. You can update it as below.

```js
const Book = new Schema({
    name: {
        type:String,
        required: true 
    }
    authors: [{}] //or [{_id: {type: Schema.Types.ObjectId}, comment: {type: String}}]
})
```

Comment: Great!! This helped me so much!! Thank you!!